# Algorithm for finding the vertices of a union of axis-aligned hypercuboids in the nonnegative orthant, all with one vertex at the origin

Tags: algorithm, geometry, language-agnostic, complexity-theory, computational-geometry

Suppose I have a collection of N axis-aligned hypercuboids in D dimensions.

Each hypercuboid has one vertex at the origin, and one vertex in the positive orthant (i.e. with all coordinates strictly positive). This latter vertex defines the hypercube, so the collection of hypercuboids can be given by a collection of vertices, one per hypercuboid.

You may assume that I have already removed from the list of hypercuboids any hypercuboids that are strictly contained within another. (At present I'm doing this via a naive O(N^2*D) algorithm. Side question: Could I do better?)

I need to find the vertices of the union of all the hypercuboids, excluding any vertices with one or more zero coordinates.

In two dimensions, there are N-1 such vertices, and they may be efficiently found by sorting the vertices on one (arbitrary) coordinate, i.e. in O(N log(N)).

How many such vertices are there in D dimensions? (With two cubes, there appears to be only one new vertex, so perhaps still N-1?) How can I efficiently find those vertices?

Comment: "I need to find the vertices of the union" - it's unclear. Do you want to represent the shape of the union in some data structure? If yes, then which one?

Comment: Also, your assumption about N-1 *new* vertices is wrong - look at what you'll get with D=3, N=3 and coordinates (3,2,1), (2,1,3) and (1,3,2)

Comment: For the data structure: a list is fine.
On the counter-example to my conjecture: yep you're right. For those who find 3D hard to visualise (like me) you can use e.g. the MATLAB cube_plot function from here http://jialunliu.com/how-to-use-matlab-to-plot-3d-cubes/ with the code:
cube_plot([0,0,0],3,2,1,[1,0,0]); hold on; cube_plot([0,0,0],2,1,3,[0,1,0]); cube_plot([0,0,0],1,3,2,[0,0,1]); hold off;
The result is https://ibb.co/j89pg0M with 4 new vertices (excluding the ones with 0 coordinates).

Comment: List of new vertices? What are you going to do with it? It usually makes sense to design a data structure **together** with a set of operations on it. Your current representation as a set of intersecting hyper-boxes is also a data structure, but probably it doesn't support all the operations you need - that's why you want to convert it to something else, right?

Comment: They enter into constraints on a linear programming problem. So a list really is sufficient.

Comment: In this case you need to build the intersection of all your hyper-boxes, not union

Comment: ... and this intersection will be a single box, defined by its vertex with minimal coordinates over all vertices

Comment: The original question contained what I need. The union is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Some abreviature: `Hj` means "Hipercuboid j", and has one vertex at origin and the opposite at `{xi, yi, zi, wi, etc}`.

If `Hi` is contained inside `Hj` then `xi<=xj`, `yi<=yj`, `zi<=zj`, and so on.

If you have **D sorted lists** of coordinates, one for each dimension, then it's easy to check if `Hi` is inner to `Hj` by simple query of indices of coordinates: `posXi<posXj` and `posYi<posYj` and `posZi<posZj`, etc. Notice the "and", not "or", condition.

If some `Hi` does not obbey the "and" rule for all `Hj`, then the vertex `i` is a new vertex.

If some coordinate `T` is "out": `posTi > posTlast` then the vertex `i` is a new vertex.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is generating the list of new vertices. Could you show how it applies to the example HEKTO gave above, (3,2,1), (2,1,3) and (1,3,2)?